# timer callback is executing even after disposing the timer

Tags: c#

I have a timer that is disposed by other main thread , but it seems the timer is not getting disposed and callback is executing even after that.In the code  i am continuously polling for the voice cal state and then again reinitialising the timer.

here is the code snippet:

```
 private void check_voice_call_State_cb(object obj)
 {
      Voice_call_state_timer.Dispose();
      outputdata = SystemUtil.trace_proc(OnlineData.ADB_PATH, "-s " + 
            OnlineData.ADB_serial[PhoneNum] + @" shell ""dumpsys 
            telephony.registry | grep mCallState""");

      Voice_call_state_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
           check_voice_call_State_cb,
           this, 
           2000,
           System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite); 

    }
```

Comment: Before calling `Dispose()` call `Stop()`??

Comment: Don't continuously (re-)allocate `Timer`s, that's not particularly cheap. Use `Timer.Change` at the end of the callback to "restart" it. To stop, set a flag (in a thread-safe manner) that the callback checks so it simply won't reschedule the timer (an optionally at the beginning to immediately return). This avoids problems with callbacks firing after you want them to more naturally than trying to time your `Dispose` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

From the [MSDN Documentation for the class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx#Remarks)

> When a timer is no longer needed, use the Dispose method to free the resources held by the timer. Note that callbacks can occur after the [Dispose()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb0225y6.aspx) method overload has been called, because the timer queues callbacks for execution by thread pool threads. You can use the [Dispose(WaitHandle)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b97tkt95.aspx) method overload to wait until all callbacks have completed.

So you need to use the other overload to wait for all the callbacks to complete.

```
 private void check_voice_call_State_cb(object obj)
 {
      using(var handle = new ManualResetEvent(false))
      {
          var disposed = Voice_call_state_timer.Dispose(handle);
          if(!disposed)
          {
                //This is a extra firing of the event, we should not process further.
                return;
          }
          handle.WaitOne(); //Wait for the dispose to finish here.
      }
      outputdata = SystemUtil.trace_proc(OnlineData.ADB_PATH, "-s " + 
            OnlineData.ADB_serial[PhoneNum] + @" shell ""dumpsys 
            telephony.registry | grep mCallState""");

      Voice_call_state_timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
           check_voice_call_State_cb,
           this, 
           2000,
           System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite); 

}
```

---

However a better solution is to use a flag to detect multiple callings then just call `Change` to set the new time for the timer to go off. This uses a lot fewer resources than repeatedly creating and disposing timers.

```
 var timerSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1)
 private void check_voice_call_State_cb(object obj)
 {
     var gotLock = timerSemaphore.Wait(0);
     if(!gotLock)
     {
         //Another instance of the timer callback is running, just return.
         return;
     }
     try
     {
         outputdata = SystemUtil.trace_proc(OnlineData.ADB_PATH, "-s " + 
            OnlineData.ADB_serial[PhoneNum] + @" shell ""dumpsys 
            telephony.registry | grep mCallState""");

         //Move this to inside the finally bock to make this happen even on a exception.
         Voice_call_state_timer.Change(2000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite); 
     }
     finally
     {
         timerSemaphore.Release();
     }    
}
```

Comment: @ScottChamberlain   hey,This timer is initialized by two threads.And at the end both thread are disposing their timer .For one thread it is getting disposed and callback is not executing at all but for the other thread it is executing.So is this solution work will work in this scenario.i am very new to c# , please forgive me if this query is stupid:)

Comment: You can't have two threads store two timers on a single `Voice_call_state_timer` variable, both timers need to be their own variables.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  yes ,both the threads have their own copy of this variable.So my question is do i need to create two semaphoreSlim variables for both threads or just one variable will do

Comment: @ScottChamberlain  yes ,both the threads have their own copy of this variable.So my question is do i need to create two semaphoreSlim variables for both threads or just one variable will do  .One more question i have which is related to another timer in which i am not reinitializing the timer , the same structure without reinitialisation of timer ,So in that case is it necessary do all of this things.I i dont initialise in callback will the problem solve or do i have to do same thing in that case also.